# Find a function $p(q)$ such that $\frac{dp(q)}{dq}q > 0$

Tags: functions

Assume $q \geq 0$. Let $$R(q) = p(q)\cdot q$$

$$\frac{dR(q)}{dq} = p(q) + \frac{dp(q)}{dq} q$$

In my econ class, we are being given $$p(q)=A-bq$$

$A,b>0$

and told that since $$\frac{dR(q)}{dq} = A - 2bq$$ therefore, $$\frac{dR(q)}{dq} < p(q)$$ for $q >0$

---

I dislike this since it seems highly arbitrary to assume a monopolist would have a function $p(q) = A -bq$. I want to find an example to consider to understand what happens if $$\frac{dR(q)}{dq} > p(q)$$

i.e. $$MR > p(q)$$ I haven't found one. So my question is, can someone find a $p(q)$ such that $$\frac{dp(q)}{dq}q > 0$$ subject to

1. $p(q) \geq 0$
2. $p(\alpha)>p(\beta)$ for $\beta > \alpha$

Note, this is strictly a math question about finding a function that satisfies these conditions.

Comment: You're going to need some more restrictions. A simple example is $p(q) = q^2$, but is that realistic?

Comment: Good point. Updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your restrictions, $dp(q)/dq$ will always be negative, so the only way $qdp(q)/dq$ could be positive is if q is negative. I'm guessing q is the quantity of some good, so it must be positive, so under your restrictions such a function does not exist.